# O365 meeting room not sending acknowledgement

Tags: office365

I am new to O365. I have a O365 tenant to which I have system access. In this O365 tenant, there are a number of meeting rooms created . My problem is that, when we send a meeting request to this meeting rooms, we do not get an acknowledgement from this meeting room. We also do not see any indication of the slots booked, on the meeting room calendar. However, if we check the availability through EWS API, we come to know that the slot has been booked. Can anyone tell me what do I need to do so that the meeting room resource can send acknowledgement of the request and how to make the confirmed slot appear on the calendar of the room.